# PDF Form Date Calculations and Restrictions?

Tags: javascript, forms, date, pdf, acrobat

I have made a PDF Form, I still have the following tasks to be done, any help will be useful:

1. Date Picker: Is there any Hijri/Gerogian Datepicker known to work on PDF Forms.
2. Date Compare: I have to date fields, want to validate the the end date field to be equal or more than the start date.
3. Calculate Date: Want to calculate the number of days between two dates.

Comment: There are many questions and answers here on #2 and #3, so really all you're after is #1, and there seems to be a number of candidates [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=PDF+javascript+datepicker&oq=PDF+javascript+datepicker&aqs=chrome..69i57.3583j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: As Acrobatusers.com got shot down, and is now read-only, some help concerning date pickers is no longer so accessible. Anyway, I have developed a date picker for Acroforms, which could be modified to fulfill point 1 in the list; for more information and quotes, feel free to contact me in private.